# How to render a complex array in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In this area, I want to enter people's `name` and `surname`. This is my small component.

```
<v-row v-for="(list,i) in getList" :key="'list-item-'+i">
    
    <v-col cols="6"><v-text-field v-model="name"/></v-col>

    <v-col cols="6" > <v-text-field v-model="surName"/></v-col>

</v-row>
```

```
data(){
    return{
          name:nulll,
          surName:null
       }
},

computed: {
        getList() {
            const newCategory = []

            const getCategory= [
                {category: 'elder', count: 3},
                {category: 'babies', count: 1},
                {category: 'children', count: 0}
            ]

            getCategory.map(item => {
                return item.count > 0 ? newCategory .push(item) : null
            })

            return newCategory 
        }
    },
```

The `getList` is an array and I filtered it if the count is not bigger than 0. My problem is about creating the right component counts for every
object. For example, there are 3 elders and 1 baby in my `getList`
array. So ı need to create 4 component forms for this.

> But in my solution I can obtain only 2 components. 1 elder and 1 baby. Sure I need to create 4 components. 3 elders and 1 baby.

Comment: In your case, the binding is always the same for all of the ones in the array. ( if you change one of those, it will change all of the fields ) Are you really expecting such a behaviour?

Comment: I saw my mistake in here . I think i must find a way for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` maps one array to another. If you start off with 3 elements as is in your case, you end up with 3 elements in the final array. How you solve that problem depends mostly on how you eventually solve the problem that you are currently mapping all name fields to the same `name` variable in your component.

You could use an `Array.reduce`, which also loops through all elements of the original array, but gives you much more freedom in what you output.

```js
const categories = [
  {category: 'elder', count: 3},
  {category: 'babies', count: 1},
  {category: 'children', count: 0}
]

const formRows = categories.reduce(
  (accumulator, item) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.count; i++) {
      accumulator.push({
        category: item.category,
        name: '',
        surName: ''
      });
    }

    return accumulator;
  },
  []
);

// Here we have an array with 4 items, 3 with category elder and one with category babies
```

Another way of solving this problem is to loop in the template itself

```
<template v-for="list in getList">
  <template v-if="list">
    <template v-for="i in list.count">
      <v-row :key="i">
        <!-- Note, these models all refer to the same variable, so they change at the same time... -->
        <v-col cols="6"><v-text-field v-model="name"/></v-col>
        <v-col cols="6"><v-text-field v-model="surName"/></v-col>
      </v-row> 
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Second solution looks clear but i don't know if it causes performance losing.

Comment: The first and seconds solution should be similar in performance. Also keep in mind that we are talking about 8 input fields, not 100's of them, so performance is unlikely to be an issue for some time. Also keep in mind that you first need to think about how to map the `v-model` of each of these fields to their own variable and choose your solution based on that.

Comment: Yes ı realized i must change v-model working logic in here otherwise i can't keep names and surnames . In my solution , i get only last entered name and surname